# Why doesn’t transaction throw a TimeoutException?

Tags: wcf, transactions

1) In the following example client-side TransactionScope TS1 timeouts. But unless TS1 calls `Complete()` and thus votes to commit the transaction, no exception is thrown:

```
TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);

using (TransactionScope scope1 = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, timeout))
{
    proxy.GetAnimal(16); // returns after 10 seconds
    Thread.Sleep(6000);
}
```

I realize that without calling Complete() the transaction won’t get committed, but I fail to see why timeout exception shouldn’t be thrown regardless of whether transaction is committed or not?!

2) Even if `proxy.GetAnimal()` is called after the transaction timeout, the call will still succeed:

```
    TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
    using (TransactionScope scope1 = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, timeout)) 
    {
        proxy.GetAnimal(); // returns after 10 seconds
        Thread.Sleep(6000); 
        proxy.GetAnimal(); // shouldn't this call cause an exception?
    }
```

Wouldn't throwing an exception made more sense?

Comment: possible duplicate of [TransactionScope and Timeout Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344082/transactionscope-and-timeout-issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [TransactionScope and Timeout Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344082/transactionscope-and-timeout-issue)